# Не видны стрелки навигации слайдера в мобильных браузерах

Tags: jquery, css

Реализован слайдер.

http://sunprice.kz/event/detail/38

НА ноутбуках и компьютерах стрелки видны сразу, но вот на мобильных устройствах, если зайти через браузер, навигации (стрелки) слайдера не видны. Где накосячи в css?

```
/* Navigation */
    .iis-previous-nav,
    .iis-next-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        z-index: 20;
        display: block;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        border-radius: 50px;
        background-size: 48px 48px;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
        -o-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
        transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    }
    .iis-previous-nav {
        left: 5%;
        background-position: 35% 50%;
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+Cjxzdmcgd2lkdGg9IjUxMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1MTIiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6c3ZnPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+CiA8Zz4KICA8dGl0bGU+TGF5ZXIgMTwvdGl0bGU+CiAgPHBvbHlnb24gZmlsbD0iI2ZmZmZmZiIgaWQ9InN2Z18xIiBwb2ludHM9IjM1MiwxMTUuNCAzMzEuMyw5NiAxNjAsMjU2IDMzMS4zLDQxNiAzNTIsMzk2LjcgMjAxLjUsMjU2ICIvPgogPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4=");
    }
    .iis-next-nav {
        right: 5%;
        background-position: 65% 50%;
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+Cjxzdmcgd2lkdGg9IjUxMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1MTIiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6c3ZnPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+CiA8Zz4KICA8dGl0bGU+TGF5ZXIgMTwvdGl0bGU+CiAgPHBvbHlnb24gZmlsbD0iI2ZmZmZmZiIgaWQ9InN2Z18xIiBwb2ludHM9IjE2MCwxMTUuNCAxODAuNyw5NiAzNTIsMjU2IDE4MC43LDQxNiAxNjAsMzk2LjcgMzEwLjUsMjU2ICIvPgogPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4=");
    }
    .ideal-image-slider:hover .iis-previous-nav,
    .ideal-image-slider:hover .iis-next-nav { opacity: 1; }
    .ideal-image-slider:hover .iis-previous-nav:hover,
    .ideal-image-slider:hover .iis-next-nav:hover { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: На каких именно устройствах? У вас вообще мобильная версия есть?

Comment: @Oceinic на любом сотовом телефоне, открываем браузер, например chrome, открываем страницу а там этих стрелок на слайдере нету(((

Answer (score 1):

```
.iis-next-nav,
.iis-prev-nav {display:block !important;}
```

Только вам это не поможет. Работать они не будут. Плагин http://idealimageslider.com/ так работает, что на мобильных устройствах скрывает кнопки и человек пальцем перелистывает изображения.

Comment: вот блин(( мне прикрутили этот слайдер, думал не буду делать, придется самому искать другой

Comment: не вижу проблемы оставить как есть. еще раз - на мобиле изображения пальцем крутятся. ну или искать другой да. к тому же у вас OWL Carousel уже подгружается (причем аж два раза). Пример как вам нужно — http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html